# V2V vCenter Server Standalone Converter

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

Environment:
VM: Server 2008 Standard R2 with vCenter Server 4.1 installed running on VMware Workstation 7.1.  I'm pretty confident I've done my homework on the required port settings that have to be opened up for this in windows firewall. 443, 902

The destination host is an ESXi 4.1 server which the vCenter Server 4.1 VM is already managing.

I install vCenter Converter Standalone client on the vCenter Server 4.1 VM and attempt to push it up to my ESXi 4.1 box.

Error:
FAILED: Unable to create a VSS snapshot of the source volume(s).  Error code: 2147754754 (0x80042302)

Resourcing that error online points me toward Windows Firewall blocking a port, but again I'm pretty sure I've opened all the requisite ports.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the converter on your Windows Host, stop the server VM and convert the VM by pointing directly at the vmx file.

Since you are running Vmware Workstation, I can't think of a good reason why you would want to migrate to ESXi from within the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Just Enable VSS Services on Source Machine the Windows Server 2008; Ensure source machine is also ON then Convert using the Option "Powered On Machine";

The ESXi server needs to be standalone not connected to any clusters.

Mathews